# Is there an rgrep alias for mac

Tags: bash

After moving from ubuntu to mac one of the commands I've been unable to live without is rgrep. I know it's possible to use `grep -r 'term' *` but is there an alias (or more likely a function) that can accomplish this without the flag and *?

Comment: Just add the function to your `.bashrc`.

Comment: `rgrep() { grep -r "$1" *; }`

Comment: Perfect, why didn't you add as an answer?

Comment: I've found including extra params (just in case) a nice addition:
    function rgrep { grep --color -I -r "$1" * $2 $3 $4 $5; }

Comment: @fmpdmb, why that instead of `grep -r "$@"`, which would handle an unlimited number of extra arguments? (Also, using `$2 $3` etc unquoted means you split apart arguments with whitespace, expand globs even if quoted to be literal, etc).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy This was before I learned about shift and why I added my followup function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about?

```
rgrep() { 
    if [ "$#" -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "Usage: $FUNCNAME pattern [options] -- see grep usage"
        return
    # one arg - pattern
    elif [ "$#" -eq 1 ]; then
        grep -rn "$@" *;
    # 2 args - flag pattern
    elif [ "$#" -eq 2 ]; then
        first=$1
        shift
        grep -rn "$first" "$@" *;
    # more than 2 args
    else 
        echo "Usage: $FUNCNAME 2+ params not yet supported"
        return
    fi
}
```

Comment: Might consider `local first=$1` to avoid leaking the variable into global scope (at a cost to compatibility -- the `local` keyword isn't in the POSIX spec, though the majority of minimal shells such ash implement it anyhow), and/or using `rgrep() {` with no `function` keyword to improve compatibility (`function` is supported by fewer shells that `local`).

Comment: This function works great! One question about it: what is the difference between: `grep -rn "$@" *;` and `grep -rn "$@" .;` _asteriks_ or _dot_ as path pattern?

Answer (score 0):

Put this into `~/.bashrc`:

```
alias rgrep='grep -r'
```

Then start a new shell to see the alias working.

Comment: This doesn't include the `*` argument as requested by the question

Comment: @chepner Thx for the hint. But I don't get what I'm missing here. Having this alias on RedHat systems and `rgrep` works as on Debian for me ...

Comment: With this, `rgrep 'term'` would block, waiting to read from standard input. The users wants the `*` (as the list of files/directories to recurse through) as part of the `rgrep` as well, but with this you would need to type `rgrep 'term' *`.

Comment: Oh, I think I got it. You mean there are different implementations of `rgrep`? One which will read stdin having no path argument, and one that will use `.` as default?. (I think that I've seen this) Then a function like `glenn jackman` suggested is indeed the solution

Comment: That sounds about right. I don't have any machines available which have a predefined `rgrep` command to check.

Comment: @chepner Now where you said this, I think to remember that difference between *waiting on stdin* or *using .* It appeared some time ago. Will need to investigate this. (even if that is true at all) Will keep the post, lets wait what the OP says.